# Приложение работает некорректно, если запустить через *.jar файл, Java

Tags: bat, jar, java

столкнулся со странной проблемой:
Моё приложение в отдельном потоке проверяет подписку пользователя каждые 2 минуты, начиная с 15й секунды после запуска (путем отправления POST-запроса, который возвращает true/ false, true - подписка присутствует, false - отсутствует соответственно).
Программа работает отлично через Intellij Idea или через *.bat файл с кодом:

```
@ECHO_ON
java -jar app_pb.jar
```

Но вот если запустить с той же директории *app_pb.jar*, после 15 секунд работы программы она выдаст что подписка отсутствует.

Как такое может быть, подскажите, один и тот же код (один и тот же *.jar файл), но работает по разному в зависимости от того, запускаю ли я через консоль либо сразу через *jar*, и обратите внимание, что ни в файле джава, ни в *.bat файле нет никаких особых свойств, 'чистый' запуск программы.

Теорий на этот счет попросту нет, для меня это необъяснимо. 
Извините если уже было, я не смог найти подобную проблему.

Comment: Запускайте из той же директории java -jar app_pb.jar

Comment: Не совсем вас понял, я же так и делаю через консоль (в данном случае батник), у меня проблемы именно с запуском *.jar файла напрямую, объясните свою мысль подробнее, пожалуйста. @Bakhuss